# Ubuntu 14.10 | Logitech Unifing | No Keyboard nor mouse during Grub choice menu

Tags: grub2, keyboard, logitech

Almost all is in the title !
I'm unable to use up/down arrows on my K800 wireless Logitech keyboard (No advertising, just trying to be accurate!)
Once grub choice menu passed after time out, both keyboard and mouse are working fine.
As I'm a fully newbie in Linux/Ubuntu, I suppose I didn't set something somewhere to enable USB unifing device on boot and grub phase.
Please help !
Raphaël

Comment: Is your keyboard plugged into a usb3 port as if so you might have to check your BIOS to allow usb3 as I had this problem on a HP.

Answer (score 1):

@ Martin Croft: Thanks a lot ! My USB ports are not 3.0 but I visited my BIOS config and found the solution: I enabled "USB keyboard" in the Peripherals tab.
When I said I was a newbie !!
Next time, I will search more deeply before asking !

Raphaël